# Return type of << operator overloading function in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

I have create a program to overload << operator for my class.
I have a doubt about the return type of the overloaded method.

When i am returning the  out from the overloaded operator function the program is working fine.

But when i am not returning any thing from the function the program crashing under one condition.

In many C++ resource i have read that the return type is necessary to print operators in cascading .

Condition 1 : Passing
   When i am using statement

`// cout<<"\n"<<mv1<<mv2<<mv3;`

Every thing is working fine. Passing without return from overloaded function.

Condition 2:Failing
When i am using statemtent
cout<<"\n"<

This i know that return was not there so the program crashed at runtime.

But the question is what made program run in Condition 1 . Even without the return statement was not present in the overloading function.

## Program below

```
I have create a program to overload << operator for my class.
```

I have a doubt about the return type of the overloaded method.

When i am returning the  out from the overloaded operator function the program is working fine.

But when i am not returning any thing from the function the program crashing under one condition.

In many C++ resource i have read that the return type is necessary to print operators in cascading .

Condition 1 : Passing
   When i am using statement

`// cout<<"\n"<<mv1<<mv2<<mv3;`

Every thing is working fine. Passing without return from overloaded function.

Condition 2:Failing
When i am using statemtent
cout<<"\n"<

This i know that return was not there so the program crashed at runtime.

But the question is what made program run in Condition 1 . Even without the return statement was not present in the overloading function.

## Program below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class myvar{

  private:
  int var_x,var_y;

  public:

  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out,myvar n);
  void setvalue(int x,int y)
  {
     var_x = x ;
     var_y = y ;
  }

};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out,myvar n)
{
cout<<"("<<n.var_x<<","<<n.var_y<<")"; 
//return out;

}


int main()
{
 myvar mv1,mv2,mv3;
 mv1.setvalue(10,20);
 mv2.setvalue(30,40);
 mv3.setvalue(50,60);

//Working

    // cout<<"\n"<<mv1<<mv2<<mv3;

//Not Working

    // cout<<"\n"<<mv1<<mv2<<mv3<<"Hello"<<1243<<11.5;

}
```

Comment: Your program should not even compile without warning. When your function signature demands a return value, but you are not returning any, any decent compiler will tell you there is  a problem. Are you paying attention to compiler warnings?

Comment: Reaching the end of the body of a function whose return type is not `void`, without encountering a `return` statement, exhibits undefined behavior (except when this function is `main`). Discussing failure modes of code that exhibits undefined behavior is not particularly interesting; that time is better spent fixing the code so that its behavior is well defined.

Comment: @SergeyA Many compilers (in my experience) won't without flags. :(

Comment: @erip, any modern ones?

Comment: @SergeyA Depends if gcc 5.3.0 is considered modern. ;)

Comment: @erip, fair enough. I see what you mean now. I am just so used to -Wall that I am not even considering it a flag. my bad.

Answer (score 3):

This code has **Undefined Behavior**.
This is very bad. Usually it means that a crash will happen (but technically anything can happen).

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out,myvar n)
{
out<<"("<<n.var_x<<","<<n.var_y<<")";  // fixed cout to out.
//return out;

}
```

This is because you specify a return type in the function signature.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out,myvar n)
^^^^^^^^
```

If your function does not contain a `return` keyword then your code is invalid. So for the function as defined (with the commented out return) your program will most likely crash.

If you change your code to:

```
void operator<<(ostream &out,myvar n)
{
out<<"("<<n.var_x<<","<<n.var_y<<")"; 
}
```

Now it will compile (be valid) and work.
But the consequence is you can not chain stream operations together.

```
 myvar  x;
 // Set some value in x

 // This will work fine.
 std::cout << x;

 // But this will fail to compile.
 std::cout << x << " Another Thing";
```

Because the first call to `operator<<` returns a void the second call to `operator<<` does not know what to do.

So your best bet is to return the stream to allow chaining.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out,myvar n)
{
    out<<"("<<n.var_x<<","<<n.var_y<<")"; 
    return out;
}
```

PS: Some space characters would be really nice to aid readability.

```
// This is easier to read for a human.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, myvar n)
{
    out << "(" << n.var_x << "," << n.var_y << ")"; 
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you always return the passed in ostream and probably want to pass in a `const` reference to the value you want outputed:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const myvar& n)
{
    out << "(" << n.var_x << "," << n.var_y << ")"; 
    return out;
}
```

Comment: It is not about returning ostream, it is about following function signature. In theory, one could create an insert operator which does not return a stream.

Comment: They should also use `out` in the function and not `cout`

Answer (score 0):

My biggest doubt is that why chaining of << in following statement

is working even without the return of out from overloaded function.

```
cout<<"\n"<<mv1<<mv2<<mv3;
```

Comment: My biggest doubt is that why chaining of << in following statement

is working even without the return of out from overloaded function.

cout<<"\n"<<mv1<<mv2<<mv3